# C# If-else Compile Error }

Tags: c#, if-statement, compilation

i just started out with C# and im confused by a Compile Error.
This is the Code:

```
namespace Control_Flow_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string UserInput;
            int Number;

            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie eine Nummer von 1-10 ein");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Number = Convert.ToInt32(UserInput);

            if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 10);
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid");
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

The } after the Console.WriteLine; seems to do the Compile Error for some Reason, how to fix it ?

[Compile Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEFMR.png)

Comment: Remove the semi colon after your if statement

Comment: Thank you alot, such a dumb mistake to fallout for >.>

Comment: happens to the best of us. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 10);` get rid of the semi colon.

With the semi colon after the `if` you have

```
if ()
a block of code
else (with no corresponding if)
a block of code
```

The semi colon ends the `if` statement and so you have a "floating" `else` with no previous `if`

Comment: 2 upvotes for an off-topic, typo question, nice! Consider yourself lucky

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Typo? sure. Off topic? why? It is not the first typo question to ever get an answer and it won't be the last. I did look for a dupe to close it (admittedly quickly) but I didn't find one and so far no one else has either (or perhaps they just haven't bothered)

Comment: Well, the typo closure is an off-topic sub-item, that's why